# Ajuda nessa consulta em SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Essa consulta:

```
SELECT C.CompanyName, MAX(SOH.TotalDue) AS Total, A.CountryRegion FROM SalesLT.SalesOrderHeader SOH
INNER JOIN SalesLT.Customer C ON C.CustomerID = SOH.CustomerID
INNER JOIN SalesLT.CustomerAddress CA ON CA.CustomerID = C.CustomerID
INNER JOIN SalesLT.Address A ON A.AddressID = CA.AddressID
GROUP BY A.CountryRegion, C.CompanyName
ORDER BY MAX(SOH.TotalDue) DESC;
```

Retorna essa lista:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Mas o que eu preciso é somente uma linha do total máximo de United Kingdom e uma linha do total máximo de United States.

Eu não to conseguindo fazer essa consulta selecionar apenas um de cada CountryRegion. Alguém me ajuda?

Comment: O maior valor de Total ou a soma dos valores de Total? Se for o maior valor, o nome da respectiva companhia deve aparecer?

Answer (score 2):

Como você está agrupando pelo CompanyName é normal que ele quebre
a linha. Para agrupar apenas pela CountryRegion você precisa excluir
aquela coluna do select.

```
SELECT MAX(SOH.TotalDue) AS Total, A.CountryRegion FROM SalesLT.SalesOrderHeader SOH
INNER JOIN SalesLT.Customer C ON C.CustomerID = SOH.CustomerID
INNER JOIN SalesLT.CustomerAddress CA ON CA.CustomerID = C.CustomerID
INNER JOIN SalesLT.Address A ON A.AddressID = CA.AddressID
GROUP BY A.CountryRegion
ORDER BY MAX(SOH.TotalDue) DESC;
```